# call function on click outside of a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a html structure as

```
<div class="abc">
  <div id="test">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="checkbox">     
  </div>
</div>
```

I want that when i click outside of **div id test**, a particular function can be called. and also no event shall be triggered when inside the **div id test** i.e  when I click the **checkboxes**, no event shall be triggered.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve it by the following code (demo : http://jsfiddle.net/CrfCD/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).click(function(e){
        if ($(e.target).is('#test,#test *')) {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Hi");
            //Perform your event operations
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
 $('.abc').click(function(e){
  if(e.target.id == 'test') {
   return false;
  }
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use: [(Demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/Techsolo/9VK8e/)

**JavaScript**

```
$('.abc').click(function(e){
    alert('Do anything');
});

$('#test').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    // Do only if anything in #test was clicked
});
```

`e.stopPropagation()` prevents from [bubbling the event to the next element](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies, the problem am facing is that when i click outside anywhere, it gets triggered, but i want is only if i click outside once from that div a function can be called

Comment: @user930026 - In my code  it triggers only in the `.abc` element. I think if you want to trigger it just anywhere but not everywhere put a `.abc` around.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the ID of the div clicked and check whether it is equal to test or not.

```
$("body").on("click", function(e) {
    if(e.target.id != "test") {
       // do something
       return false;
    }
    else {
       return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).click(function(e){
   if(e.target.id == "test"){
     e.preventDefault();      
     e.stopPropagation();   
   }
   else{
      //your function call that you want to invoke on clicking anywhere outside of div _test_
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
   if(e.target.id == 'test') {
        alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    }

});
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/c6UEm/49/)

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="abc" onclick="getId()">
```

JavaScript:

```
function getId() {
    --Write your function here--
}
```

Comment: HTML :<div id="abc" onclick="getId()">

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
   if($(e.target).is("#test")){
     e.preventdefault();
     e.stopPropogation();
   } else{ 
     //call your method
   }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to limit the call of function only once. I.e on click outside of a div a event to be triggered only once. The problem is event gets triggered timne and again

Answer (score 1):

Use the Div focus event, so as it will only be called once when the div looses focus. Refer to the post [Div - onblur function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504139/div-onblur-function)