# Div - onblur function

Tags: html

I want to call an `onblur` on a `div`. How can I get it done?

I tried this:

```html
div onblur="javascript:callme()"
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: I think div not support onBlur!

Comment: thanks, but can i have any solution for this problem

Comment: see  this post to find possible events: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7284379/which-dom-events-can-be-bound-to-a-div-element

Comment: If I know correctly, only AREA, BUTTON, INPUT, LABEL, SELECT, TEXTAREA create focus/blur events, div doesn't. what you want to do.

Comment: I don't think you can focus on a div so you wouldn't be able to blur off of it. What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

For the `blur` event to fire on an element, the element needs to receive focus first. But `<div>` elements do not receive focus by default.

You can add `tabindex="0"` or `contentEditable` to your *div*, so it will receive focus.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/t25rm/

Comment: Note that you can use a [negative value for tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) (`tabindex="-1")` if you don't want the element to be accessible by e.g. keyboard, but still have `onFocus` and `onBlur` events.

Answer (score 28):

The blur event fires when focus is lost. By default, a div element cannot have the focus in the first place so it **can't** be lost.

If you set `tabindex` on a div, then it can gain the focus, but you should almost always be using a more appropriate element (such as a button) when you think about making interactive controls.

```
<!-- Not recommended. See above -->
<div tabindex="1" onblur="callme()"> content </div>
```

Comment: any idea how compatible this is (I wouldn't do it just curious)

Comment: Pretty widely AFAIK, but it is a silly thing to do so I've never used it in practise and never needed to worry about the support.

Comment: Why not, I mean, what if you want to change the class(s) (or other attributes, etc) on a set of controls within said `<div>` ?

Answer (score 11):

If you give the div a tabindex attribute, it will be able to accept focus:

```
<div id="yourdivid" tabindex="0">content</div>
```

then attach focus and blur event handlers
For example:

```
document.getElementById("yourdivid").onfocus = function() {
   alert('focused');
}
document.getElementById("yourdivid").onblur = function() {
   alert('blur');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle focus lose on children of the div, then you need to use 'onfocusout' event instead of blur.

Example:

```
<div onfocusout="console.log(123123)" tabindex="0" contentEditable>
... some content which can accept focus
</div>
```

Comment: [loose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loose) is not the same as [lose](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lose#Verb). What do you mean? Do you mean [loss](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loss#Noun) of focus?