# Native JavaScript - detect when a div is clicked away from / unfocused

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to know when my div is clicked away from, in native javascript.

Comment: Unless your div is contenteditable, it doesn't have a focus/blur event

Comment: The only real way to do this would be to set a flag, and then to unset it (for instance on another div's click event)

Comment: This question has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504139/div-onblur-function

Comment: Is the div a kind of pop up or overlay? If the div is on top of a faded background that takes up the entire rest of the space then you can fire you script what that background is clicked.

Comment: Is it a kind of dialogue where the background is an overlay? In that case it's when the background is clicked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test whether or not the element that was clicked is the element in question using only native javascript code you can do something like this

```js
var handleClick = function(e) {
  var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
  if (e.target !== div) alert('clicked outside of div');
}
document.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
```

```css
/* For the purposes of this example only */

div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```