# How can I remove all child element of DIV element on onBlur event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I have a web page where I have defined one DIV element with id "selectedProduct", now while I click on particular link it will call ajax request and it will fill DIV element with response data. But i have requirement that when onBlur event occurs on "selectedProduct" DIV, it should remove all the child element of it's. My code is as follow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getPage(event,id)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var page = document.getElementById(id).id + ".html";
    var dataString = page               

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: page,
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result)
        {
            var result=result;

            $("#selectedProduct").html(result);
            //  location.replace("index1.html");                                                
        }
    });
}

function focOFF(id)
{
 // I don't have any idea what code should i write here which can remove all child of DIV element....
}
</script>

<body>
<a href="#selectedProduct" style="text-decoration:none" id="solar_power_plant" target="new" onClick="getPage(event,this.id)" class="scroll">Solar Power Plant</a>

<div id="selectedProduct" onBlur="focOFF(this.id)">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Is onBlur event can be used with DIV element?? I think its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below solution of getting all child elements and the removing them,

```
function focOFF(id)
{
    $( "#"+id ).children().remove();
}
```

Comment: Is onBlur event can be used with DIV element?? I think its not working.

Comment: Follow this for making onblur in a div http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504139/div-onblur-function

Answer (score 0):

Use [**empty(**)](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) function inside your blur function . It removes all child nodes of selected element

```
function focOFF(id)
{
  $('#'+id).empty();
}
```

Comment: Is onBlur event can be used with DIV element?? I think its not working.

Comment: when do you want to delete child items of div ? on click ?

Comment: onBlur event it should remove all child

Comment: onblur doesnot work for div.. check onmouseout event for div and call above function for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: Is onBlur event can be used with DIV element?? I think its not working.

Comment: What do you mean under on blur div? Which behaviour do you want to achieve?

Comment: when mouse leaves div element then div should get empty, it means all child of div should be removed.