# Need to save content of a div when focus is out of it

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

Currently two div (it can be anynumber also), so if I move mouse pointer from one div to another div, whatever wrote in first div should be saved (I have function to that). My issue is that when I move from one dive to another, jquery function is not getting called. So I tried onblur function, onmouseleave function etc but its not working, it work only on first time load. Is it because of the way I'm appending function in dynamic binding? Please anyone help

```
function createNewStickyNote() {
    i++;
    var row = $("<div>", { id: "divStickyNote_" + i, class: "mybox" }, onblur = onblurFunction())
            .append($("<div>", { class: "boxtitleLeft" }).html("<img src='Images/Plus.png' height='23px' width='23px' onclick=createNewStickyNote()  >"))
            .append($("<div>", { class: "boxtitleRight", }).html("<img src='Images/Delete.png' height='23px' width='23px' onclick=deleteStickyNote('divStickyNote_" + i + "','divData_" + i + "')  >"))
            .append($("<div>", { id: "divData_" + i, class: "boxcediv", contenteditable: true }));

        row.draggable({ handle: ".boxtitleLeft,.boxtitleRight" }).resizable();     
        $("#div_Main").append(row);
        popup_bar = document.getElementById("divStickyNote_"+i);
        popup = document.getElementById("divStickyNote_"+i);
        offset = { x: 0, y: 0 };         
        popup_bar.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);            
        return false;
}

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="div_Main"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: `<div>` elements by default cannot receive focus, so therefore cannot lose it, which is why your `onblur` function is not called. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504139/div-onblur-function). You can add `tabindex="0"` or `contentEditable` to your `div` so it will receive focus.

Comment: Thanks @mikeyq6 . Issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

`tabindex="0"` and `contentEditable` should solve your problem.

As a sidenote, you should beware about doing things with focus triggers, as they are not always reliable. A user may not move the mouse out of a box, and use TAB instead.

If the form that holds the notes have a hotkey for closing the form, the function for saving the sticky notes to a database may save the old data before the new data is refreshed.

It all depends on the rest of the code, but it's a thing to keep in mind

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the last 5 lines of your 'createNewStickyNote' function are doing - what about something like (as you are using JQuery) to bind the event handler to the newly added divs

```
row.on('mousedown', mouseDown);
```