# Javascript blur event on wrapper div

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events, blur

I have inner input field and a wrapper div element.
I have added `contenteditable` attribute to the div element in order to be able to set focus on it.
I would like to catch the **onblur event of the div**.

Now, If I'm in focus on the input field and click with the mouse on different place in the screen
the blur event of the input field is called of course but not the blur event on the div.
Of course this makes sense - this is how the browser works.

But anyway,
I was wondering if and how it is possible to achieve that.

```
  <div id="wrapperDiv" contenteditable class="wrapperDivClass">
      <input id="innerId">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved when I changed the blur event to **focusout**

From MDN web docs:
**The focusout event is fired when an element is about to lose focus. The main difference between this event and blur is that the latter doesn't bubble.**

This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

For blur event to fire on an element, the element needs to receive focus first. But  elements do not receive focus by default.

You can add `tabindex="0"` or `contentEditable` to your div so it will receive focus.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/t25rm/

Answered here:
[Div - onblur function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504139/div-onblur-function)

Comment: thanks but this is not what I'm asking here..
I can catch the blur on the div - but it's not good enough for my use case..
I need to be able to catch the blur event of the div regardless to where the mouse clicked on the screen after leaving the div