# Span or Div tag onblur and onfocus

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I understand that the Div or Span tags do not apply onblur or onfocus.
Why not apply?
Is there any element that doesn't work?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to help you construct better questions.

Comment: That is functionality forinput elements. They behave differently to layout elements. It makes no sense to add these events to layout elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blur and Focus are both events of input elements, e. g. text input fields. Focus is fired when the input element gets the focus so you can type, blur when the input element looses the focus.
span and div elements are not focussable in the way input elements are; they are just layout elements, nothing a user really interacts with. Therefore, spans and divs have no focus or blur event.

Comment: Joerg, the use of 'contenteditable' permits DIV and SPAN to have focus and blur events.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504139.

Answer (score 0):

Joerg is right but HTML element may have a `contenteditable="true"` option and in this case you can use `.addEventListener("focusout", () => {})` instead `.onblur = () => {}`. And it will be working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).