# onBlur Not Working in React Dropdown Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, styled-components, react-component

I have created the following React Dropdown Component:

```
const Dropdown = ({
  titleTag = 'button',
  titleCss,
  title,
  icon,
  menuCss,
  children,
  open,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false)

  const handleClick = () => setIsOpen(state => !state)
  const handleBlur = () => setIsOpen(false)

  return (
    <DropdownBase>
      <Trigger
        as={titleTag}
        css={titleCss}
        onClick={handleClick}
        onBlur={handleBlur}
      >
        {title}
        {icon}
      </Trigger>
      <Submenu css={menuCss} open={isOpen}>
        {children}
      </Submenu>
    </DropdownBase>
  )
}
```

My problem is that the menu will not close if I click outside of the menu.  I can open and close the menu by clicking on it.  But I cannot close the menu by clicking away from the menu -- which is what I thought would happen with the `handleBlur` function.  Indeed, that very function worked **before** I refactored the dropdown menu into a component.

So, what do I have to do so that the dropdown menu will close whenever I click outside of the dropdown menu?

Thanks.

**Note:**  In case it is relevant, here are the relevant Styled Components that make up the Dropdown:

```
const DropdownBase = styled.div`
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
`

const Trigger = styled.div`
  cursor: pointer;
`

const Submenu = styled.div`
  display: ${props => (props.open ? 'block' : 'none')};

  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 20;

  ${Link} {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
  }
`
```

Comment: try to give the component a `tabindex`

Comment: Should the handler be like `const handleBlur = () => setIsOpen(state => false);`?

Comment: @URL87 I did, no difference.

Comment: @MarkusZeller  I tried that also -- didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `div` element can't receive `focus` event, you can add `tabindex="0"` to your `Trigger` component.

[can you see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504139/div-onblur-function)

Comment: I changed the `Trigger` component to a `button` tag and it now works  Thanks.  Note for anyone else in a similar situation, `tabindex="0"` did **not** work for me.

Comment: **CORRECTION:**   `tabindex` does work -- however, I forgot to capitalize the 'i'.  In other words, it is `tabIndex="0"`, **not** `tabindex="0"`.