# jQuery - Run function when clicking outside element

Tags: jquery

In this code I can open the `.options` menu when I click the `.select` element however because I use e.stopPropagation(); on the `input` option to allow the menu to close, I need to incorporate `e.target` so that if it isn't the target, the menu will close (allowing for click outside).

How do I use `e.target` to hide the `.options` menu when clicking away or if I click `.select` a second time?

```js
$(".select").each(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
    options = $this.find(".options");

  $this.click(function(e) {
    $(".options").attr("hidden", "hidden");
    options.attr("hidden") ?
      options.removeAttr("hidden") :
      options.attr("hidden", "hidden");
  });
  options.find("input").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".options").attr("hidden", "hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.select {
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 1.3rem 0;
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer
}

.selected {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.options {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.options[hidden] {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
}

.options input {
  display: none;
}

.options label {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  padding: 10px;
}

.options label:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <div class='selected'>
    <div class="selected__text">Click Me</div>
  </div>
  <div class="options" hidden="hidden">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="First">Click to Close
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="Second">Click to Close
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- No need for `.each` it'll be enough to work with a single event
- Working with a class it will be much easier than `hidden` attribute
- For window click I used to use this function below

Your code will looks like this [This code will work with multiple select]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".select").on('click' ,function(e) {
    var options = $(this).find(".options");
    $('.options').not(options).addClass('hidden');
    options.toggleClass('hidden');
  });
  $(".select .options").find("input").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest(".options").addClass('hidden');
  });
  on_window_click('.select , .options' , function(){
    $(".options").addClass('hidden');
  });
});


// Functions
function on_window_click(elem , action){
  $(document).on('click',function(e){
    if (!$(elem).is(e.target)
    && $(elem).has(e.target).length === 0)
    {
      action();
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.select {
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 1.3rem 0;
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer
}

.selected {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.options {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.options.hidden {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
}

.options input {
  display: none;
}

.options label {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  padding: 10px;
}

.options label:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <div class='selected'>
    <div class="selected__text">Click Me</div>
  </div>
  <div class="options hidden">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="First">Click to Close
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="Second">Click to Close
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div>Another Select</div>
<div class="select">
  <div class='selected'>
    <div class="selected__text">Click Me</div>
  </div>
  <div class="options hidden">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="First">Click to Close
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="Second">Click to Close
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Function Explanation:**

> `on_window_click(elem , action);`
>
> **elem** : The elements you need to avoid/target
>
> **action** : The action function to run when clicking outside the
> avoid/target elements

**Don't forget to replace**

**html** : `class="options" hidden="hidden"` with `class="options hidden"`

**css** : `.options[hidden]` with `.options.hidden`

Answer (score 1):

You can try toggle attr:

```js
$(document).click(function(e) {
  let options = $('.select').find(".options");
  options.each(function(e){
    !$(this).attr("hidden") && $(this).attr("hidden", "hidden");
  })
});

$(".select").each(function(e) {
  var $this = $(this),
    options = $this.find(".options");

  $this.click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    options.attr('hidden', function(index, attr){
        return attr == 'hidden' ? null : 'hidden';
        });
  });
  options.find("input").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".options").attr("hidden", "hidden");
  });
});
```

```css
.select {
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 1.3rem 0;
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer
}

.selected {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
}

.options {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column
}

.options[hidden] {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
}

.options input {
  display: none;
}

.options label {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  padding: 10px;
}

.options label:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <div class='selected'>
    <div class="selected__text">Click Me</div>
  </div>
  <div class="options" hidden="hidden">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="First">Click to Close
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="Second">Click to Close
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a tabindex to the options div, you can use an onblur on it, which should do the trick. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18504302/5774952). It would be better to use a styled `select` in this case though, both for accessibility and because it seems like you're replicating the same functionality using `div`s which is the hard way around :)